# Cypress.io and https error

Tags: https, cypress

I am using cypress.io for the first time and get an error message in the tool which I think has to do with https and "site not secure". Please see attached pictures.
I assume this has to do with cypress not running "outside" the browser as Selenium, but operates directly on the DOM, thus this security issue. In other tools I have imported a certificate to cope with similar problems, but are there anyways to do similar in cypress or how can I solve these kind of issues?
Thanks!

[image: regular browser error (not in cypress tool]

[image: error]

Comment: [Cypress isn't just browser code](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/general-questions-faq.html#Does-Cypress-use-Selenium-Webdriver). It can extend outside of the Javascript sandbox, and as a result It has ways of getting around https errors. Currently, there is [a known issue if you are connecting to an unsecure site via IP address](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/771#issuecomment-404907167), but that does not appear to be your issue. It is very likely you are experiencing something unrelated. What is your platform / version / etc?